# Tablesorter - sort odd and then even numbers

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Can anyone help me in writing a parser for Tablesorter that sorts a column of numbers and puts the odd numbers first and then the even numbers, in ascending sequence

Many thanks

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm new to this and a haven't a clue where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

Prepend an 'A' to all the odd numbers.
Sort.
Remove the 'A's

Comment: How would I fit that solution in with Tablesorter

Comment: There are sortStart and sortEnd events you can hook into.

Comment: Would it be possible to show me the code as I'm a complete noobie.

Comment: Yes it's possible but that is not what Stock Overflow is all about.

Comment: Thank-you Steve. Could you point me in the right direction as to where I can get the needed help?

Answer (score 0):

The following method will only work with my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), because the `textExtraction` function in the original version (2.0.5) does not allow assigning the text extraction per column, and this method needs an alphanumeric sort algorithm to work properly ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2298/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    textExtraction: {
        0: function (node, table, cellIndex) {
            var num = parseFloat(node.textContent);
            return num % 2 ? num : 'even' + num;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's great, thank-you so much for your help. Could I ask one more thing.

Comment: I have a number of columns in my table and I want to sort on the second column and then the first column (with the odd and evens). What would I need to add?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want.